# Navbar navigation with id and sticky content sections

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll, sticky

This might be hard to explain in words but I'll try my best, for better understanding I am also providing codesandbox link.
I have 5 sections with each section being sticky, each section sticks up on other one which creates cool stacking effect. I have a navbar that too is sticky and has navigation links. When any nav link is clicked, app scrolls down to that section. I am using id for scrolling. Navigation works fine when I am scrolling from top to bottom but when I try to click any nav link when I have already scrolled to bottom part, it doesn't come up to respective section. Technically it scrolls but because of position sticky that respective section doesn't show up as it is under some other section. How to fix this?

Here is my codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-river-tzlk9g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did you try using `IntersectionObserver`?

Comment: I didn't, how can this be implemented with IntersectionObserver? @mandy8055

Comment: This library might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer